# Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. django 2.1

Tags: python, django

So trying to launch my first django app, it is a simple Morphological Analyzer page that get a japanese sentence from a form and then goes to another page with the results,but im getting this error  Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted as i try to send the form.
My template:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>日本語の構文解析</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static'bunseki/style.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="header">
   <h1>日本語の構文解析</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="sidebar">
     このサイトは形態素解析器JUMANを使用し、文を形態素(Morpheme)単位に分割する。
   </div>
   <div class="main">
   <div class="bun">
    <form method="post">
          <h1>解析したい文<h1><br>
          {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form }}
      <br>
      <button type="submit">解析</button>
    </form>

  </div>

<div class="footer">
```

My view:

```
def index(request):
    form = KaisekiForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            request.session['kaiseki_bun'] = request.POST['kaiseki_bun']
            return redirect('kaiseki')
    return render(request, 'bunseki/index.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Do you try delete application cookies from browser.

Comment: Do you have csrf middleware enabled in `settings.py`?

Comment: yes and yes, same result